# How to use XmlAttributeOverrides with WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xmlserializer

I have a WCF service using basicHttpBinding.  On a service method I have a class that is returned, for this class I need to dynamically / programmatically exclude properties and change property names for the XML.  This needs to be done both in the WSDL and when the service method is called.

I have searched for the best solution and it seems that I will need to (1) use the XmlAttributeOverrides with the XmlSerializer or (2) implement the IXmlSerializable on the class that needs to be customized.  Or there may be a better solution altogether.  I know that Property Name + "Specified" can be added to the class and then those properties can be excluded.  However, this does not exclude in the WSDL and this doesn't solve the property renaming issue.

Why do I want this?  Because of globalization and customization of our application.  There are many properties that are built into our application that may be renamed or hidden entirely from users of the application.

After MUCH research I the best option is to swap out the WCF serializer with my own custom serializer.  However, I never found good examples of how to do this for a custom class that would use the XmlSerializer.  Also I'm not sure how I would pass in the XmlAttributeOverrides for a specific class.

Also, this might not be the case for others who want this same functionality but in my application I only need to initialize the values once for the lifetime of the app.  Too bad C# doesn't allow static readonly variables to be used with attributes.

Here is an simple example of a class:

```
public Customer
{
  public string Address1
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string Address2
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string Zipcode
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

In this example I would like to for certain installations of the application use PostalCode instead of Zipcode and hide the Address2 property.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 1):

> There are many properties that are built into our application that may be renamed or hidden entirely from users of the application.

A standard approach is to create a special Data Transfer Object (DTO). Or several.

Comment: Isn't any class with properties a DTO?  I think I already have a DTO the issue when building xml and xml schema from the DTO I need to dynamically exclude and rename the properties.  Can you link an article about a "standard approach" using DTO's in WCF to achieve this?

Comment: And DTO's are nothing special (on the contrary). Point is they are designed for the Transfer job.

Comment: The idea that webservices appear differently based on installation of an app isn't uncommon.  Look at salesforce.com, one company's wsdl would look very different from another companies because of the extensibility of the application.  This is similar, the webservices are different based on the apps configuration which is generally done at installation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this seems like a bit of a cop out, but since your object property names are dynamic why not just use property bagging instead of doing this XMLSerializer shuffle?

Comment: The OP mentions the WSDL etc - also, a property-bag offers almost *no* choice over the serialization layout.

Comment: The property bag would change my property names to indexer strings, giving me the flexibility to pick names in real time.  However, I don't think the wsdl and client consuming objects would really get good definitions for the property indexers or data types.  I really need better structured XML and schema.  I'll add an example to my OP.